# GOOGLE COLAB ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install an earlier version of inferpy in google colab but I keep getting this error. I can install the latest version with no error. I tried solutions that works for local machines but none of them worked out for me.

my code:

```
!pip install inferpy==0.0.3
```

the error I get:

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/d7/825b509d4067e09571f58a3ab86bdf0672134e67c51cb126c2e0d3a47127/inferpy-0.0.3.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

any ideas how this can be resolved?
thanks

Comment: This is the error `ERROR: inferpy-0.0.3.tar.gz is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+).`. I recommend you to use newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [project homepage](https://pypi.org/project/inferpy/0.0.3/) this old version only works with:

- Python :: 2.7
- Python :: 3.4

Source: https://pypi.org/project/inferpy/0.0.3/

Your colab notebook most likely is in a newer version of python 3 thus the error, (I got similar problem when trying to use *unirest* which depends on *poster* that only works in Python2)

One option you may have is the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467489/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-3-5-instead-of-3-6):

[Is there a way to use Python 3.5 instead of 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467489/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-3-5-instead-of-3-6)