# Is it possible to run a more recent version of Python on colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm sorry this question was closed. As I mentioned in my comments, I know about the other answers. I'm now convinced that there is no good answer. But this question was not a duplicate of previous questions and should not have been closed on those grounds.

---

When I run

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

I get `3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27)`.

Is it possible to get colab to run a more recent version of Python?

Comment: Probably the same answer as early questions on earlier versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467489/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-3-5-instead-of-3-6 + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010692/google-colab-choosing-specific-python-version

Comment: I saw those, but using local hardware is not a good solution in my case. I'm using colab so that I can work with a group of people without asking them to install anything. One of the prime benefits of colab is that it works without requiring that one install anything. I'd like to stay within that paradigm.

Comment: What I really want is a way to encourage colab to bring themselves up to date. Of course it's free, and you know the saying about getting what you pay for. But it's so disappointing to have a nice system like colab and then finding that Google seems to be letting it get run down. Why do they do that? It looks so bad.

Comment: @RussAbbott, I proposed a solution without local hardware use in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775160/install-python-3-8-kernel-in-google-colaboratory/71511943#71511943