# Downgrade python version from 3.7 to 3.6 in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Some python packages wont work in python 3.7 . So wanted to downgrade the default python version in google colab.Is it possible to do? If so how to proceed.Please guide me..

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467489/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-3-5-instead-of-3-6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use Python 3.5 instead of 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467489/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-3-5-instead-of-3-6)

Answer (score 11):

You could install python 3.6 with `miniconda`:

```
%%bash

MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT=Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
MINICONDA_PREFIX=/usr/local
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
chmod +x $MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
./$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT -b -f -p $MINICONDA_PREFIX
```

And add to path:

```
import sys
_ = (sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"))
```

Comment: Getting error while running command     ....   %%bash
cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Object_detection/models-master/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .

Comment: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.

Comment: `%%bash
cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Object_detection/models-master/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .`

Comment: `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.`

Comment: I ran, but cells still run on python3.9

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the following methods:

1)

```bash
!apt-get install python3.6

!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2

!python3 -V
```

2. 

```
%env PYTHONPATH = # /env/python

!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!./Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda update conda

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')

!conda create -n myenv python=3.6


# Also, if you want to downgrade TensorFlow to a previous version:
%%shell
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate myenv
pip install tensorflow==1.15
# pip install tensorflow_gpu==1.15
```

Comment: Option 1 works but when I want to go to an even lower option, for example:
`!apt-get install python3.2

!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.3 1
!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.2 2

!python3 -V`

It is still on 3.7 rather than lower?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet below will download Python 3.6 without any Colab pre-installed libraries (such as Tensorflow). You can install them later with pip, like `!pip install tensorflow`. Please note that this won't downgrade your default python in colab, rather it would provide a workaround to work with other python versions in colab. To run any python scripts with 3.6 version, use `!python3.6` instead of `!python`

```
!add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
!apt-get update
!apt-get install python3.6
!apt-get install python3.6-dev

!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3.6 get-pip.py

import sys

sys.path[2] = '/usr/lib/python36.zip'
sys.path[3] = '/usr/lib/python3.6'
sys.path[4] = '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
sys.path[5] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
sys.path[7] ='/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'
```

Comment: I got this error : `ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py instead.`

Replace the link with `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py` instead and make sure you deleted the _get-pip.py_ that was downloaded previously before executing.