# Downgrade python version to the exact version in google colab (from 3.7.12 to 3.6.9)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-3.6, python-3.7, downgrade

I need to downgrade my python version to 3.6.9.
Although [Downgrade python version from 3.7 to 3.6 in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775948/downgrade-python-version-from-3-7-to-3-6-in-google-colab) was helpful, it only changed it to 3.6.5.
Please tell me how i can get the exact version i want in google colab

Comment: Generate a requirements.txt from the colab and create an environment based on it.

Answer (score 0):

This version is on end-of-life, but here is the direct link to install Python 3.6.9

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-369/

Comment: Isn't there any command in Google Colab to install it directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following methods:

1)

```bash
!apt-get install python3.6

!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2

!python3 -V
```

2. 

```
%env PYTHONPATH = # /env/python

!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!./Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda update conda

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')

!conda create -n myenv python=3.6


# Also, if you want to downgrade TensorFlow to a previous version:
%%shell
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate myenv
pip install tensorflow==1.15
# pip install tensorflow_gpu==1.15
```