# Did colab suspend tensorflow 1.x?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I tried

```
%tensorflow_version 1.15
```

I used this code a couple days ago, but it doesn't work anymore since today.

The outcomes are

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-24c52e77c597> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('tensorflow_version 1.15')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2158         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2159         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2160         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2161 
   2162     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2079                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2080             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2081                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2082             return result
   2083 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/_tensorflow_magics.py in _tensorflow_version(line)
     39 
     40              Your notebook should be updated to use Tensorflow 2.
---> 41              See the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#migrate-from-tensorflow-1x-to-tensorflow-2."""
     42                        ))
     43 

ValueError: Tensorflow 1 is unsupported in Colab.

Your notebook should be updated to use Tensorflow 2.
See the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#migrate-from-tensorflow-1x-to-tensorflow-2.
```

Is there any method I can try to fix it or does it means that colab will not support tensorflow 1.x anymore?

Comment: I get the same problem - shouldn't it be possible to just install 1.x with pip and then modify it somehow, its obviously a hassle but far easier than the alternative...

Comment: Using !pip install tensorflow==1.15.2 instead of %tensorflow_version 1.x works for me - it does however appear that colab is substantially slower now...

Comment: It seems work for me too. Maybe you'd better using tensorflow-gpu==1.15 instead of tensorflow.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks let me check it out

Comment: It is much faster using the "tensorflow-gpu==1.15" massive thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google Colab removed support for Tensorflow 1, and it is not possible to use `%tensorflow_version 1.x` magic anymore. You must remove this instruction from your code if you have it.

Also the default python version as I update this answer is python 3.8 which is not compatible with tensorflow 1.x.

To make everything work you first have to downgrade python. Python 3.6 should work. As suggested by [@s-abbaasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2962705/s-abbaasi) here's a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776080/2962705) on how to do so:

```
%%bash

MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT=Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
MINICONDA_PREFIX=/usr/local
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
chmod +x $MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
./$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT -b -f -p $MINICONDA_PREFIX
```

Then add to path:

```
import sys
_ = (sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"))
```

At this point you can manually uninstall and re-install tensorflow through `pip`:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15
```

Doing just so I sometimes encounter some errors due to the Cuda version. If this happens to you, you can execute the following:

```
!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn7=7.4.1.5-1+cuda10.0
```

The most appropriate version of cuda and libcudnn to use with the tensorflow version you want to install can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).

The versions available of libcudnn can be found with the following command:

```
!apt list -a libcudnn7
```

This will list all `libcudnn7` versions available.

Comment: Exception is raised anyway

Comment: You have to remove the `%tensorflow_version 1.x` instruction that can’t be used anymore. Installing manually replaces the instruction @kubinka0505

Comment: Uninstalling done but while running `!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15` the following error raises:

`Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0,...)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15`

Comment: I think they recently updated the python version in google colab to 3.8 which is not compatible with tensorflow 1.x. The solution would be to downgrade python. @s.abbaasi

Comment: Thanks @ClaudiaR. Downgrading python works for me. Here is a guide to downgrade: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776080/2962705
I recommend you to add downgrade solution to your post. So other users can consider it.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problems while trying to use StyleGAN2-ADA, which only supports TensorFlow 1.

I found out that unfortunately **Google Colab removed support for TensorFlow 1 in their latest release of 2022/8/11.**

> 'Removed support for TensorFlow 1'

You can find more information in their notebook Release-Notes: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/relnotes.ipynb

Comment: Probably the most annoying thing Google has done, it takes money and engineering work to restructure massive codebases to TF2 from TF1.

Comment: It seems that only tf2 is supported by Colab, but that's not true, you still can use pip to uninstall tf2 and install a specific version of tf1. !yes|pip uninstall tensorflow, !pip install tensorflow==1.15.5 Maybe you should install other dependencies. So use !pip install -r requirements.txt Attention! You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.

Comment: @ClaudeCOULOMBE Your suggestion now fails with `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.5 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.15.0rc0, 2.15.0rc1)
`.