# Install tensorflow 1.x on colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Now that Google Colab is not supporting tensorflow 1.x is there a way to install it through e.g. pip and set up your environment in a similar fashion to what the old %tensorflow_version 1.x did? I really really dont want to rewamp all my code to TF 2

Comment: `!pip install tensorflow==1.15` and restart

Comment: Tensorflow 1 is unsupported in Google Colab. Hence this code `%tensorflow_version 1.x`  to convert runtime TF version into 1.x will not work. However you can install TF 1.x using the code mentioned in the above comment -  `!pip install tensorflow==1.15` to suffice your code requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did colab suspend tensorflow 1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215696/did-colab-suspend-tensorflow-1-x)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only tf2 is supported by Colab, but that's not true, you still can use pip to uninstall tf2 and install a specific version of tf1. !yes|pip uninstall tensorflow, !pip install tensorflow==1.15.5 Maybe you should install other dependencies. So use !pip install -r requirements.txt Attention! You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by creating a virtual environment using the conda suggested by Atotem in the GitHub Thread.

You can check this thread:
[issues-3266](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3266#issuecomment-1348660900)