# How to solve Tensorflow 1 becomes unsupported in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

As Tensorflow 1 becomes unsupported in Google Colab and StyleGAN2-ADA only works with Tensorflow 1.
Can anyone help what I should do to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason to not move to the [pytorch version](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch)?

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work, if you want to run TF1 code under a recent version of TF2

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

(Instead of *import tensorflow as tf*, of course)

In TF 2.9.1 this is available but deprecated, and it will likely disappear
in a not-too-distant future version

Comment: I've got this error after writing this solution "Import "tensorflow.compat.v1" could not be resolved", how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Tf1 code on Google Colab you can uninstall the default installation of TensorFlow (Tf2) and install Tf1 manually, for example like this:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73426036/14774959) might also be helpful.