# google colab only works with tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run the following google colab:

https://colab.research.google.com/gist/zsyzzsoft/5fbb71b9bf9a3217576bebae5de46fc2/data-efficient-gans.ipynb?authuser=1#scrollTo=Re5R6VX8VNgo

colab no longer recognises gpu's with tensorflow 1.x. so is there any way to get this colab working again??

I have tried reinstalling to tensorflow 1.x and also upgrading the code to tensorflow 2 but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73426036/14774959

Comment: i came across this, but it didn't work. just ended up using the pytorch version. :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab removed support for Tensorflow 1, and it is not possible to use **%tensorflow_version 1.x** magic anymore. You have to install a specific version of tensorflow 1.x version using

```
pip install tensorflow==1.x
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

For more details please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009682/how-to-tell-if-tensorflow-is-using-gpu-acceleration-from-inside-python-shell?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top). Thank You.